# Manjaro not booting on clean install

Tags: linux, boot, manjaro

I removed all the partitions on my SSD to use it only for Manjaro.

I tried [this method](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Installation_to_SSD_%28quick_guide%29) and it completed succesfully, but my laptop didn't boot.

When I use the GUI installer I get a warning about the bootloader not being installed correctly, and it doesn't boot either - I get a message saying "Please install an OS".

All I need is a clean install of Manjaro on my empty SSD.

Comment: What did happen when it didn't boot?

Comment: I saw some message saying "please install an os"

Answer (score 1):

You probably booted in UEFI mode with a legacy BIOS install
or
you booted in legacy mode with an UEFI install
or
you booted in UEFI mode with an UEFI install, but you have to add a new boot option in the BIOS